# SQL - adding something to one column if another column meets criteria

Tags: mysql

so... same table.  I'm working in phpMyAdmin.

If column A contains 'thingOne' then add 'thingTwo' to column B

```
UPDATE `table` SET tablefield = replace(tablefield,"your mom","my mom");
```

I can do find / replace.

For column B too, I want to add to what's already there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UPDATE `table`
SET columnB = CONCAT(columnB, 'thingTwo')
WHERE columnA = LIKE '%thingOne%'
```

Comment: correct!  thank you so much =)  I already dug in, and got it.  I feel kind of silly, actually.  the -3 is deserved.  sorry guys =/  if I could upvote you, I would!